# How to select Parents rows and Child rows with only specific columns

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

So I have two tables that have a layout like (but not named):

```
Table A
-------
AID
Title
ACol1
ACol2 ... (to ACol60)
```

and

```
Table B
-------
BID
AID
Title
BCol1
BCol2 ... (to BCol30)
```

I built a simple class

```
public class SimpleCollection
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SimpleCollection> Elements { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is two fold:

1. Return in a single call all the parent/child rows.
2. Select only the columns I need so I'm not pulling the 60/30 extra columns I don't need.

I tried the following:

```
var query = from A in dbContext.TableA
            from B in A.TableB
            select new SimpleCollection()
            {
                ID = A.AID,
                Title = A.Title,
                Elements = select new SimpleCollection<string>()
                {
                    ID = B.BID,
                    Title = B.Title
                }
            };
```

But it doesn't like setting Elements to a select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I was over thinking the problem.

```
var query = dbContext.TableA
                     .Select(p => new SimpleCollection()
                     {
                       ID = p.AID,
                       Title = p.Title,
                       Elements = p.TableBs
                                   .Select(c => new SimpleCollection()
                                   {
                                     ID = c.BID,
                                     Title = C.Title
                                   }
                     }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from A in dbContext.TableA
            from B in A.TableB
            group B by A into g
            select new SimpleCollection()
            {
                ID = g.Key.AID,
                Title = g.Key.Title,
                Elements = g.Select(x => new SimpleCollection {ID = x.BID, x.Title}).ToList()
            };
```

Comment: The `g.ToList()` does not convert the type of `g` into a `SimpleCollection` type does it?

Comment: Won't `query.ToList()` return me duplicate TableA rows?